# position: fixed и ширина контейнера

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

```css
.bottom-nav {
  background-color: #444;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: green;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Resp bottom nav bar</h2>
    <p> Resize the brovser to see how its work</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-nav">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">News</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

1)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

никак не пойму что делает такого pos:fixed что bottom-nav без нее не растягивается на всю ширину

Comment: Похоже на баг эмулятора. Посмотрите ширину `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ссылки используют `float: left` из за чего родитель схлопывается, добавьте родителю `clearfix`

```css
.bottom-nav {
  background-color: #444;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: green;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Resp bottom nav bar</h2>
    <p> Resize the brovser to see how its work</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-nav clearfix">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">News</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
  </div>
```